# How to cross data from 2 excel sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm doing a small internship at a local library.
My mentor requested my help to a do lenghty job, but it has to be done over the week.. So, this is what he requested me: to look up in 2 different excel sheets data that could be combined. Easy enough doing ctrl+F.. The thing is that it has over 7.400 different users to search from.

The final sheet looks like this:
ORGANIZATION  |  LAST NAME  |  FIRST NAME  | JOB TITLE  |  E-MAIL  | PHONE

Second Sheet

LAST NAME | FIRST NAME | E-MAIL | PHONE

All fields from the "final sheet" are filled except for "E-MAIL" and "PHONE".. These are the ones to be filled with the information from the "Second Sheet".

Is this possible? I know that this is possible using Microsoft Access, but other than that can't I use a Macro or something (I have zero to no experience in Excel :/ )

P.S. - Some users from the "Second Sheet" don't have neither "E-MAIL" nor "PHONE" information.. Will this mess up the macro?

Comment: Assuming you have exact matches, you should be able use VLOOKUP or HLOOKUP (make sure to specify exact matches), and won't need to any macros.

Comment: Oh, thank you :) . I'll look up for more information on those commands!

Comment: To add to ernie's remark:  you'll likely want to concatenate the LAST NAME and FIRST NAME into helper columns on both sheets.  Insert the the helper columns to the left of the values, since VLOOKUP needs to look to the right.

You will quickly grow to love VLOOKUP.

Answer (score 2):

Perfect job for [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx).

Insert a column on `Second Sheet` to the right of `First Name` and enter `=concatenate(B2,C2)` and drag it down to get `LastNameFirstName`. *Replace B2 and C2 with the appropriate starting cells.*

Now in the `E-MAIL` column of `Final Sheet` put `=Vlookup(concatenate(A2,B2),'Second Sheet'!$D$2:$E$99,2,False)` to pull the email from the first sheet. Replace E99 with whatever the last cell is in the email column. Also replace A2 and B2 with the appropriate starting cells.

In the `PHONE` column of `Final Sheet` you can use the same type of vlookup `=Vlookup(concatenate(A2,B2),'Second Sheet'!$D$2:$F$99,3,False)` to drag down and capture phone numbers.

Anyone that has a blank will return a blank and anyone that isn't found will return `N/A`